# Using Spring as backend while using JSF for client-side

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, spring-mvc, jsf

I am creating a web application that will basically register users onto a website where they can log-in and browse an inventory of items, much like a store. The user info and store items will be stored in a MongoDB.

For the server/back-end side, I plan on using Spring RESTful services implementation to communicate with the MongoDB and perform the CRUD operations when necessary.

Now my main question is what to use for the client-side (Browser rendering, web pages, etc). I am considering either JSF, along with Facelets for the view, or Spring MVC and Facelets for the view.

If I use JSF for my client-side, will this architecture work?

Comment: You can use Spring MVC and and Facelets together but not Spring MVC and JSF. You were already told about it in your immediate previous question. Spring is an enormous framework having sever modules in it. Spring MVC is merely one of them. You cannot use Spring MVC and JSF together, since both of them are MVC frameworks. You can use JSF on top of the Spring platform (again not Spring MVC - both of them refer to different things).

Comment: It will work, but you end up duplicating/replacing many things already offered out the box by JSF (or Java EE) that one would start wondering why exactly you're using JSF (or why exactly you choose the Spring path instead of the Java EE path).

Answer (score 0):

Spring and JSF working well together.
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html
http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-faces.html

You can choose any framework for the frontend application and call your backend with REST Calls.